# My RESTful API isn't updating the database, but ajax returns success

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

I've built a simple API following this tutorial [here](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html)
When the user clicks on a room they're prompted with does the room need to be cleaned, if the user taps yes, an ajax request is made to the update section of my API. The request returns success, but for some reason the database isn't updated. I know there is no problem connecting to the database as I can read information from the database no problem. 
Below is a small snippet of the front-end where the calls are made.

```js
//loop through room cells and add click listener
var roomCells = document.getElementsByClassName("zui-sticky-col");
for (i=0; i<roomCells.length; i++) {
  $(roomCells[i]).attr('data-room', i);
  $(roomCells[i]).on('click tap', function() {
    cleanFlag(this);
  });
}
//destroy modal 
$("body").on('click tap', '#closeIt', function() {
  destroyModal();
});
//destroy modal 
$("body").on('click tap', '.no', function() {
  destroyModal();
});
//add clean event
$("body").on('click tap', '.yes', function() {
  addClean();
});
//remove clean event
$("body").on('click tap', '.yesClean', function() {
  removeClean();
});
//function to schedule clean flag
function cleanFlag($this) {
  var attribute = $this.getAttribute("data-room");
  roomClean = attribute;
  $("body").addClass("lock");
  $(".zui-scroller").addClass("lock");
  $("body").append("<div class='overlay'></div>");
  $("body").append("<div class='modal'></div>");
  $(".modal").append("<p class='close'><i id='closeIt' class='far fa-times-circle fa-2x'></i></p>");  

  if (! $('[data-room='+roomClean+']').find('.fa-exclamation-circle').length) {
    $(".modal").append("<p class='modalTxt'>Does This Room Need to Be Cleaned?</p>");
    $(".modal").append("<div class='responseWrap'></div>");
    $(".responseWrap").append("<div class='no'>No</div>");
    $(".responseWrap").append("<div class='yes'>Yes</div>");
  }
  else {
    $(".modal").append("<p class='modalTxt'>Has This Room Been Cleaned?</p>");
    $(".modal").append("<div class='responseWrap'></div>");
    $(".responseWrap").append("<div class='no'>No</div>");
    $(".responseWrap").append("<div class='yesClean'>Yes</div>");
  }
}
// function to add clean flag
function addClean() {
  var temp = roomClean +1;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //rest Type
    url: "https://alteredego.org/markiii/inn_api/rooms/update.php",
    dataType:'text',
    data:JSON.stringify( {"room": temp, "dirty": "1"}),
    success : function(data) {
    $('[data-room='+roomClean+']').append('<br><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>');
    },
    failure: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      console.log(" Sorry I can't do that right now. Please try again. ", errorMessage );
  }
  });
  destroyModal();
}
// function to remove clean flag
function removeClean() {
  var temp = roomClean +1;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //rest Type
    url: "https://alteredego.org/markiii/inn_api/rooms/update.php",
    dataType:'text',
    data:JSON.stringify( {"room": temp, "dirty": "0"}),
    success : function(data) {
      $('[data-room='+roomClean+'] i').remove('.fa-exclamation-circle');
      $('[data-room='+roomClean+'] br').remove();
    },
    failure: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      console.log(" Sorry I can't do that right now. Please try again. ", errorMessage );
  }
  });
  destroyModal();
}
// destroy modal
function destroyModal() {
  $(".modal").remove();
  $(".overlay").remove();
  $("body").removeClass("lock");
  $(".zui-scroller").removeClass("lock");
}


//function to schedule clean flag
function cleanFlag($this) {
  var attribute = $this.getAttribute("data-room");
  roomClean = attribute;
  $("body").addClass("lock");
  $(".zui-scroller").addClass("lock");
  $("body").append("<div class='overlay'></div>");
  $("body").append("<div class='modal'></div>");
  $(".modal").append("<p class='close'><i id='closeIt' class='far fa-times-circle fa-2x'></i></p>");  

  if (! $('[data-room='+roomClean+']').find('.fa-exclamation-circle').length) {
    $(".modal").append("<p class='modalTxt'>Does This Room Need to Be Cleaned?</p>");
    $(".modal").append("<div class='responseWrap'></div>");
    $(".responseWrap").append("<div class='no'>No</div>");
    $(".responseWrap").append("<div class='yes'>Yes</div>");
  }
  else {
    $(".modal").append("<p class='modalTxt'>Has This Room Been Cleaned?</p>");
    $(".modal").append("<div class='responseWrap'></div>");
    $(".responseWrap").append("<div class='no'>No</div>");
    $(".responseWrap").append("<div class='yesClean'>Yes</div>");
  }
}
//add room flag
function addRoomFlag(data) {
  for (i=0; i < data.room.length; i++) {
    if(data.room[i].dirty == 1) {
    $('[data-room='+i+']').append('<br><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>');
    }
  }
}

// here are ajax calls *********

// make json call for room status
$.ajax({
  type: "get", //rest Type
  url: "https://alteredego.org/markiii/inn_api/rooms/read.php",
  processData: true,
  data: {},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    addRoomFlag(data);
    }
});
 
// function to add clean flag
function addClean() {
  var temp = roomClean +1;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //rest Type
    url: "https://alteredego.org/markiii/inn_api/rooms/update.php",
    dataType:'text',
    data:JSON.stringify( {"room": temp, "dirty": "1"}),
    success : function(data) {
    $('[data-room='+roomClean+']').append('<br><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>');
    },
    failure: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      console.log(" Sorry I can't do that right now. Please try again. ", errorMessage );
  }
  });
  destroyModal();
}
// function to remove clean flag
function removeClean() {
  var temp = roomClean +1;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //rest Type
    url: "https://alteredego.org/markiii/inn_api/rooms/update.php",
    dataType:'text',
    data:JSON.stringify( {"room": temp, "dirty": "0"}),
    success : function(data) {
      $('[data-room='+roomClean+'] i').remove('.fa-exclamation-circle');
      $('[data-room='+roomClean+'] br').remove();
    },
    failure: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      console.log(" Sorry I can't do that right now. Please try again. ", errorMessage );
  }
  });
  destroyModal();
}
```

```css
.zui-sticky-col {
    border-bottom: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
    z-index:3;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    min-width:100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.modal {
    width:80%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color:white;
    padding-left:.8em;padding-right:.8em;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.overlay {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.modal input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius:none;
    display:block;
    width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#3d3d3d;
    color: #e84118; 
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 16px 0px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.modalTxt {
    padding: 15px 0px; 
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #3d3d3d;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
}
.close {
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 0px; 
    margin: 0;
    color: #e84118;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: right;
}
#closeIt {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-times-circle {
    color:inherit;
}
.lock {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 61px);
}
.responseWrap {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.no, .yes, .yesClean {
    padding: .8em 1em;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.no {
    background-color: red;
    color:white;
}
.yes, .yesClean {
    background-color: green;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 1</div>
 <div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 2</div>
<div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 3</div>
<div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 4</div>
<div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 5</div>
<div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 6</div>
<div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 7</div>
<div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 8</div>
<div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 9</div>
<div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 10</div>
<div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 11</div>
<div class="zui-sticky-col">Room 12</div>
```

Below is a portion of my API that pertains to this issue

```
    // Rooms class (rooms.php)
<?php
    class Rooms{

        // database connection and table name
        private $conn;
        private $table_name = "********";

        // object properties
        public $room;
        public $dirty;

        // constructor with $db as database connection
        public function __construct($db){
            $this->conn = $db;
        }

        // read rooms
    function read(){

        // select all query
        $query = "SELECT
                     p.room, p.dirty
                FROM
                    " . $this->table_name . " p

                ORDER BY
                    p.room";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;
    }
    // update the room
    function update(){

        // update query
        $query = "UPDATE
                    " . $this->table_name . "
                SET
                   dirty =:dirty
                WHERE
                    room =:room";

        // prepare query statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

        // sanitize
        $this->dirty=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->dirty));
        $this->room=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->room));

        // bind new values
        $stmt->bindParam(':dirty', $this->dirty);
        $stmt->bindParam(':room', $this->room);

        // execute the query
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    } ?>

// update (update.php) this is the main driver
<?php
// required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/rooms.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// prepare product object
$rooms = new Rooms($db);

// get id of room to be edited
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

// set ID property of product to be edited
$rooms->room = $data->room;

// set product property values
$rooms->dirty = $data->dirty;

// update the product
if($rooms->update()){
    // set response code - 200 ok
    http_response_code(200);

}

// if unable to update the room, tell the user
else{

    // set response code - 503 service unavailable
    http_response_code(503);

}
?>
```

I have a feeling this issue is some how related to the call I make with ajax to push the room status but I'm not sure. I know this is a wall of code with little to go on but any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is too much code, you need to narrow it down.

Comment: I've been trying to but I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

Comment: The css seems unrelated and if you get an unexpected result in your javascript, only that function would seem relevant.

Comment: It's working fine for me, I tried with params "room 1 | dirty 1" and it was written, down fine in your rooms and also with "room 1 | dirty 0" it's working fine.

I think your problem is this: var temp = roomClean +1; you need to parse it in number before add the "+1"

Try with parseInt(roomClean)+1

Comment: @jeroen but the problem is I dont know if it's JS related as I dont get any errors. I feel the CSS is needed so when someone runs the snippet all my elements with event listeners have proper padding to actually be clickable and some functions work by adding or removing css.

Comment: @Margon Thank you, that solved the issue, and explains why sometimes the database would be updated. If you want to answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comment above, the issue there is the code

```
var attribute = $this.getAttribute("data-room");
roomClean = attribute;
```

and

```
var temp = roomClean +1;
```

since "$this.getAttribute("data-room");" return a string, you need to parse it in number before the add.

So the code becomes:

```
var temp = parseInt(roomClean)+1;
```

For further note, I would change the functions:

```
addClean() | removeClean()
```

with just another parameterized function (with a boolean or a number 1/0 as you whish)

```
function cleanFunction(clean) {

  var temp = roomClean +1;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //rest Type
    url: "https://alteredego.org/markiii/inn_api/rooms/update.php",
    dataType:'text',
    data:JSON.stringify( {"room": temp, "dirty": clean}),
    success : function(data) {
    $('[data-room='+roomClean+']').append('<br><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>');
    },
    failure: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
      console.log(" Sorry I can't do that right now. Please try again. ", errorMessage );
  }
});
  destroyModal();
}
```